# How to use NSThread with UILocalNotification to show custom view?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application of **Fake incoming call**.

For that, i am right now using local notification.

I am getting notification as per the set time but it gives me the pop up, like a by default notification.

Instead this, i have to show the view from either XIB or by codeing.

So, is there any way to set the custom view with localnotification?

Or can i use NSThread to get the above mentioned output?

If anyother way to get the disered output, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

---

This is what i am doing to set the notification.

```
-(void)addNotification
{

        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
        [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Answer"];

        [localNotification setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n %@",[txt_CallerName text],[txt_CallerNumber text]]];
        [localNotification setHasAction: YES];
        [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system

    [alertNotification setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: @casperOne... can you say why my code is not getting proper format at the time of adding in the question part...this is being the resonable to decrease my reputation everytime....thanks for reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing a custom interface on receiving a `UILocalNotification` is not possible right now. It is possible if you happen to receive the `UILocalNotification` when your app is in the foreground. But if it is in the foreground, you could show your custom interface regardless.

The way you catch the local notification firing and do something when that happens is by implementing `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` in `UIApplicationDelegate`. Arguably, it is the answer to your question, but it won't achieve what you're clearly looking for, which is to start your app at a specific point in time by showing custom UI, because it will only happen while the app is already in the foreground.

Comment: but is there any kind of possibility to set view instead pop up at the time of notification is fired...?

Comment: Like I said: no. You can show any custom UI *while the app is in the foreground*, but you don't need a `UILocalNotification` to do that. It is not possible to bring your app to the front or show your own custom UI when your app is in the background.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter to throw notification and event occurred just call the notified method and display your custom view.

1.Register the Notification as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displayCustomView) name:@"EventNotification" object:nil];
```

2.When event occur notify method as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EventNotification" object:nil];
```

3.In notified method display your custom view as follows:

```
-(void)displayCustomView
{
   //initialize custom view and display as required.
}
```

Comment: @Jesper... can you help me for the problem i am facing...?